# C# windows form application combobox usage error

Tags: c#

I want to select and add the publisher with the combobox on the add book page of the C# windows form application, but I am getting this error.

> The parameterized query '(@Name nvarchar(14),@Price nvarchar(2),@Description nvarchar(9),' expects the parameter '@PublisherId', which was not supplied.

My code :

```
private void bookAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            con.Open();

        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("insert into Book (Name, Price, Description, BarcodeNumber, PageCount, PublisherId, AuthorId, CategoryId) values (@Name, @Price, @Description, @BarcodeNumber, @PageCount, @PublisherId, @AuthorId, @CategoryId)", con);

        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", bookName.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", price.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", description.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BarcodeNumber", barcodeNumber.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PageCount", pageCount.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PublisherId", comboPublisher.SelectedValue);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AuthorId", comboAuthor.SelectedValue);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CategoryId", comboCategory.SelectedValue);

        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

        MessageBox.Show("Book added.");

        foreach (Control item in Controls)
        {
            if (item is TextBox)
            {
                item.Text = "";
            }
        }
}

private void AddBook_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Publisher ", con);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();           

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            comboPublisher.Items.Add(dr["Name"]);
        }

        con.Close();

        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("Select * from Author ", con);
        SqlDataReader dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();

        while (dr2.Read())
        {
            comboAuthor.Items.Add(dr2["NameLastName"]);
        }
        con.Close();

        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("Select * from Category ", con);
        SqlDataReader dr3 = cmd3.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dt3 = new DataTable();

        while (dr3.Read())
        {
            comboCategory.Items.Add(dr3["CategoryName"]);
        }

        con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Any chance the `comboPublisher` doesn't have any selected value? Then you'd be passing `NULL` as the value - and the parameter would not be valid (and thus would be claimed to be missing).

Comment: ["AddWithValue is Evil"](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/) - please read the article and stop using it!

Comment: Even though I select combobox it throws null value

Comment: But when you look at the code that loads your publishers - it seems you *only* add the `name` to the combobox list - so what are you expected to get as the `PublisherId` as the `SelectedValue` then???

Comment: I don't understand then how should I do

Comment: "_Even though I select combobox it throws null value_" let me guess, you are making a website and loading the combo in every single post (not only in the initial load). If that is the case, check `Page.IsPostback` property.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're simply not really binding the `PublisherId` value to the combobox - so even though you can *select* a publisher - you have no way of getting its `PublisherId` from the combobox.

Try something like this - define a specific class to hold these two items:

```
public class PublisherSelectDto
{
    public int PublisherId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And then use this piece of code (basically for each of the comboboxes - to get text and the respective "Id" for the value chosen):

```
con.Open();

// select *ONLY* those columns you really need!     
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT PublisherId, Name FROM dbo.Publisher ", con);

SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();           

// create a typed list of your defined class    
List<PublisherSelectDto> publishers = new List<PublisherSelectDto>();

while (dr.Read())
{
    string name = dr["Name"];
    int publisherId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["PublisherId"]);
    
    publishers.Add(new PublisherSelectDto { Name = name, PublisherId = publisherId });
}
con.Close();

// define the display and value members for your combo box     
comboPublisher.ValueMember = "PublisherId"; 
comboPublisher.DisplayMember = "Name";

// bind the loaded typed list to the combobox    
comboPublisher.DataSource = publishers;
```